# Suppressing validation for a subsection of XML

Tags: java, xml-parsing, dtd

We have a bog-standard `javax.xml.*` parser that slurps up a big XML file and tries to validate it against a custom DTD.  The DTD is stored locally, and we're validating using transformers [like in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1096365/validate-an-xml-file-against-local-dtd-file-with-java) from some years back.

All of that works.  The trouble we're seeing now is that the XML format for this type of file is written by the devil.  I'm not kidding; the specification is over 750 pages and is signed "Love, Satan."

Specifically, part of the XML looks like this:

```
<KnownTag>
    <ArbitraryTag> ... text ... </ArbitraryTag>
    <Whatever>     ... text ... </Whatever>
    <fj9e8jer23tj> ... text ... </fj9e8jer23tj>
    ....
</KnownTag>
```

The inner tags are balanced -- the raw syntax is known to be well-formed XML at this point -- but the element names themselves are completely arbitrary and unpredictable.  (Yes, it's that evil.  The company that originally published this spec has long since gone out of business because their products were notoriously unreliable.  Go figure.)

Our custom DTD can specify `<!ELEMENT KnownTag ANY>`, but we're having fits with the content.  Obviously the validating parser gives errors as soon as it hits the first user-specified element name (*element type "ArbitraryTag" must be declared*), and obviously we can't truly "validate" anything inside that block from a purely parsing context.  I'm hoping to find some way of suppressing the errors for just that section of XML.

- The parser's error handler interface, [ErrorHandler](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/org/xml/sax/ErrorHandler.html), specifies 3 callbacks; its `error()` is called in this case.  If I can figure out from [the actual exception passed in](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/org/xml/sax/SAXParseException.html) that we're inside a `KnownTag` block, then I can safely ignore the error and keep going.  Is this safe to do with the Java SE implementation?
- Getting to the arbitrary elements afterwards shouldn't be a problem, since the XML parser itself has already built a DOM Document by this point.
- The API for `javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder[Factory]` and `javax.xml.transform.Transformer` don't seem to permit toggling `DocumentBuilderFactory#setValidating()` midway through the parse.  If that's the case it won't be surprising, but I'm hoping that I've just missed something.  Anyone?

Comment: How exactly is `<ArbitraryTag>` different from `<fj9e8jer23tj>` ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [xml dtd- how to avoid parsing the content of an element?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3595060/xml-dtd-how-to-avoid-parsing-the-content-of-an-element)

Comment: @Woot4Moo It's no different.  It's "the first user-specified element name", like I said.

Comment: @artbristol Sort of.  I'm not asking how to skip the validation, I'm asking how to suppress the errors.  The ErrorHandler + SAXParseException links above don't seem to give enough information to determine that I'm parsing that particular tag...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DTDs have no mechanism for skipping validation on particular subtrees of well-formed XML; that's one of the differences between DTDs and later schema languages like XSD and Relax NG, which introduce wildcards to make it possible to say things like "The `KnownTag` element can contain arbitrary XML" (or:  arbitrary elements not in a particular namespace, or in any of a particular set of namespaces, or ...).

Whether your parser has a facility to turn error reporting off in a particular subtree is entirely parser-specific; you'll need to describe just which of the many Java-based XML parsers you are using.  The chances are slim; it's not impossible for a parser to have such a feature, but at first description it doesn't sound like spec-conformant behavior.  (It's also not a feature I've ever heard of a DTD-based validator having, but that doesn't actually prove much.)

Comment: Oh well, it was worth a try.  Thank you for confirming it!  As to the parsers:  the implementation is whichever ships with JavaSE 7u10 by the names `javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder` and `javax.xml.transform.*`.  I don't know whether those have recognizable codenames ("we're using the Bumblepuke parser") or not; these sorts of projects-on-fire get dumped on me without much prep time.  :-)

Comment: There _is_ a way using an SGML parser, but the setup is nontrivial and has an air of voodoo about it for those unfamiliar with the technique.  That was a historical aside.  XML DTDs (and their processing) were deliberately crippled, so looking for alternatives in RNG- or WXS-space is probably the way to go.

Comment: OK, now you've got me curious - what method do you have in mind for solving this problem with an SGML parser?  Can it be described concisely?